# Extracting text with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get information from the following page:         http://fantasynews.cbssports.com/fantasyfootball/players/updates/187741

I need to get separate strings for each of these items:

1. News Title
2. News
3. Analysis

Right now I am able to get information from the whole table using:

```
 doc = Jsoup.connect("http://fantasynews.cbssports.com/fantasyfootball/players/updates/" + playerId).timeout(30000).get();
 Element title = doc.select("[id*=newsPage1]").first();
```

But the result of this is all of the articles run together.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use more elaborate css selectors. Maybe something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(.*)News\\:\\p{Zs}(.*)Analysis\\:\\p{Zs}(.*)", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
  Document doc = null;
  try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://fantasynews.cbssports.com/fantasyfootball/players/updates/187741").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
  } catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(0);
  };

  Elements titles = doc.select("table h3");
  for (Element title : titles){
    Element td = title.parent();
    String innerTxt = td.text();
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(innerTxt);
    if (mat.find()){
      System.out.println("titel = " + mat.group(1));
      System.out.println("news = " + mat.group(2));
      System.out.println("analysis = " + mat.group(3));
    }
  } 
}
```

I suggest you look into css selectors and the [JSoup documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html).

Comment: Can you help with the code missing for the search functionality?  I was unable to find details at the link you posted.

Comment: Great answer!  Thank you.  Is it possible to pull the date for each entry easily using this solution?  Also, are you available for freelance Jsoup help?

Comment: this uses actually more regex than JSoup... and of course you can extract each entry - just use a map to store the title/news/analysis triple. then you should attach the date maybe too as key. or use the player id from the url and title. i don't know - whatever makes sense. Usually I don't do much freelance work, but you can contact me over odesk (id=PrivateBusiness) or elance (id=activinvest) if you want.

Comment: Thank you lunksch.  I promise to look you up for the next jsoup/regex task.  In the meantime, would it be possible for you to add the article date to your solution above?

Comment: Sorry, I am busy with other tasks - it is very unlikely that I will be available as a freelancer any time soon... There is really many people out there that you can hire for such tasks. From my experience I recommend odesk, since it has the cleanest interface for the employer side.